# Should `$srandom` apply to seed for `$urandom_range`?

Tags: random, verilog, system-verilog

Using ModelSim it looks like the seed random call with `$srandom` does not apply to subsequent random value generation with `$urandom_range`.

Running the process:

```
initial
  begin
  $srandom(42);
  $display("1: %0d, %0d, %0d", $urandom_range(1, 10), $urandom_range(1, 10), $urandom_range(1, 10));
  $srandom(42);
  $display("2: %0d, %0d, %0d", $urandom_range(1, 10), $urandom_range(1, 10), $urandom_range(1, 10));
  $srandom(42);
  $display("3: %0d, %0d, %0d", $urandom_range(1, 10), $urandom_range(1, 10), $urandom_range(1, 10));
  end
```

the output is:

```
# 1: 3, 1, 7
# 2: 9, 7, 2
# 3: 6, 4, 8
```

However, I had expected that line 1, 2 and 3 where identical, since `$srandom` was called be fore with same seed value.

Why are the generated values not the same?

Comment: As toolic mentioned, `$srandom` is not part of IEEE1800 (SystemVerilog); or IEEE1364 (Verilog). There is an `srandom()` in IEEE1800

Comment: OK, thanks, looks like ModelSim accepts it in some cases, but I see that it is not part of the standard.

Comment: Modesim _accepts_ `$srandom` with an error saying it doesn't recognize a user-defined PLI routine. That is the same thing as ignoring it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `process::self().srandom()` instead of `$srandom`. Then you get the desired results.

Comment: @dave_59 Is there a way to reseed a procedural block from the outside? I posed a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178751/how-to-reseed-the-rng-of-a-static-process